# How can I modify the user profile picture used to log-in? (Lubuntu 10.9)

Tags: lubuntu

[There was a similar question asked 7 years ago, but I do not have enough points to comment in that thread]

I'm running Lubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine, clean install yesterday) and tried the following procedure:

1. Saved a 200x200 pixel JPG picture as PNG
2. Renamed it as .face
3. Copied it into my /home// folder

Neither sign-off/sign-on nor reboot changed anything.
Is there a way to find out what is wrong?
Please note that I have no prior experience with Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and the Ubuntu community. Lubuntu 19.10 is the 2019-October release (ie. *yy.mm* format for releases) which has 9 months of supported life, reaching EOL (*end-of-life*) this month. If it's a new install, I'd consider starting again (upgrade via re-install of Lubuntu 20.04 LTS which has a supported life of 3 years as a *long-term-support* release; 5 years applies only to Ubuntu) as you'll need to *release-upgrade* in the coming days to that release anyway. If you `file ~/.face` what type of file does the system detect it as? (add detail to your question)

Comment: OK.  I'll look into getting 20.04 asap.  For what concerns the file characteristics, the system returns .face: PNG image data, 200 x 200, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced.

Comment: If you want to keep user files etc, you can re-install using "*Manual Partitioning*", selecting your existing partitions and it won't erase your user data.  A *release-upgrade* (letting your system upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04) takes hours (depending on internet speed, plus your machine speed), compared to 15-25 mins for a install. A clean install (with format) means you'll start again. By selecting existing partitions & ensuring you don't have the 'format' box checked, it'll note your packages installs, erase system dirs install, then re-install your additions without touching user data

Comment: OH, how make it work on my lubuntu? copy or mv your picture to `/usr/share/sddm/faces/your_user_name.face.icon` Make sure that the file is readable for others.  Make sure that in `/etc/sddm.conf` under block [Theme] `EnableAvatars=true` is set. for control you can use command  `sddm-greeter --test-mode` I think that was it.

Comment: I left it in my /home folder and just renamed it as .face.icon (works OK now)